# What is a color blob? Is it possible to use clustering algorithm to color blob detection problem?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, image-classification

Wiki gives this definition of blob detection

> In computer vision, blob detection methods are aimed at detecting regions in a digital image that differ in properties, such as brightness or color, compared to surrounding regions. Informally, a blob is a region of an image in which some properties are constant or approximately constant; all the points in a blob can be considered in some sense to be similar to each other. The most common method for blob detection is convolution.

based on which, is there 8 separate color blobs in this figure?

[image]

Is it possible to use clustering algorithm to color blob detection problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can use DBSCAN to solve this trivial toy example. Because it can do connected-components, and this image is trivial to threshold.

It will just be much much slower than the usual convolution-based methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The value of 8 is the correct number of color blobs in this case, right?

Comment: Depends on the actual definition you use, not an informal Wikipedia "definition".

Comment: Would you please give a more formal definition about color blob?

Comment: I'm not doing blob detection. But I'd assume a common definition would be a connected component of pixels which differ in color by at most x.

Comment: Does the "x" in "differ in color by at most x" mean some numeric value, such as grayscale?

Comment: Or some other measure of color similarity.

Comment: Would you please provide some examples about "some other measure of color similarity"?

Comment: Hue similarity for example, or LAB.